# How to make BundleTransformer SCSS and SASS compile on runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundletransformer

I recently updated BundleTransformer to 1.8.2 and it no longer is compiling my SCSS on runtime which is very inconvenient because I have to rebuild the solution each time to view a CSS change which is annoying as before I could just refresh the page.

With the update were there new parameters added for handling compiling? I've been looking through the documentation with no luck: (http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%201.8.2)

The BundleTransformer.SassAndScss is up to date with the .Core code. It doesn't matter if I'm running in Debug or Release mode it doesn't update the .scss file or the bundled file until I rebuild the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I recently updated BundleTransformer to 1.8.2 and it no longer is
>   compiling my SCSS on runtime which is very inconvenient because I have
>   to rebuild the solution each time to view a CSS change which is
>   annoying as before I could just refresh the page.

It seems to me that you are doing something wrong, because BundleTransformer.SassAndScss translates Sass/SCSS code in runtime and rebuilding of project is not required. Give me an example of bundle registration code from your project.

> With the update were there new parameters added for handling
>   compiling? I've been looking through the documentation with no luck:
>   (http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bundle%20Transformer%201.8.2)

Yes, this information there is no in the documentation, but when editing settings in the Web.config file a displays appropriate prompts. In addition, names of these properties a coincide with the names of original compiler properties - http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options

Comment: It appears that it was my machine. I restarted Visual Studio and it still wasn't working properly then I restarted my machine and it seems to be working properly now. I wasn't aware of being able to use those `sass` properties in the web.config so thanks for that!